# Time to execute re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do some substitution in a huge text file using regular expressions like this:

```
repeatedPtn_1=r'[^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}})*[^{}]*'

repeatedPtn_2=r'[^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}})*[^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}})*[^{}]*'

pattern=r'{{\s* RQ:'+repeatedPtn_1+r'(?:passage|text|quote)\s*=('+repeatedPtn_1+r')}}'

out_text=re.sub(pattern, r'{{quote-Temple:\1}}', out_text, flags=re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)
```

So if I use `repeatedPtn_1` in my pattern I get results in less than 10 minutes, but if I use `repeatedPtn_2`, which is the most suitable for me, my laptop keeps running for hours without finishing!

So may someone explain to me why and help me to find a solution?

Comment: Hi. I found this article that may help. https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: where did you get the `{{` syntax

Comment: What is `out_text`?

Comment: Have you tried yet [`[^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}}[^{}]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/QbcCHU/1) as the repeated pattern? Your `repeatedPtn_2` easily [explodes](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html) [in the provided sample](https://regex101.com/r/pxQU87/1) whereas your `repeatedPtn_1` [takes ~30x more steps](https://regex101.com/r/qyVQqX/1).

Comment: What is some typical input? Is it line-oriented? What is the typical line-length? What ***percentage*** of the input is actually changed (typically)? 100%? 10% 0.0005%? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77165514/edit), not here in comments, as appropriate (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar—the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: Please provide a text sample to test against and explain what it is you're trying to achieve. I am amazed that catastrophic backtracking hasn't been detected.

Comment: For pertinent background here, see the Russ Cox paper [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast (but is slow in Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ...)](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) -- that paper talks about how the original formulation of regular expressions wasn't prone to the kind of problem you've hit here, but the folks behind PCRE didn't understand the theory and so built something far worse than the original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The second sub pattern (when placed in your final regex):

```
[^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}})*[^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}})*[^{}]*
```

gets into trouble when it fails to match a long input (e.g. one that only has a single brace in it, not double, and where that single brace occurs *far* in the input): it will backtrack to check with one less character matched in the first `[^{}]*`, and one in the middle `[^{}]*`, ...etc, leading to a Cartesian product of sizes for the left, middle and right occurrence of the `[^{}]*` patterns. This is "catastrophic backtracking", as can be seen in [this test on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HCxaiU/1): There I embedded the pattern between `RQ:` and `passenger` and provided a paragraph of input that has the `RQ:` prefix, but not the `passenger` suffix.

To solve this, ensure these left, middle and right subpatterns never get to match **adjacent** characters. In other words, `(?:{{[^{}]*}})` must match at least once. And if that is not possible, the next `[^{}]*` should not even be considered.

So:

```
[^{}]*(?:(?:{{[^{}]*}})+[^{}]*){0,2}
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/HCxaiU/2) the same test with this updated regex.